# SwiftUI: ForEach in Picker doesn't update

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an array of elements, from which I want to chose one using `Picker`, and I have a `Button`  which simply adds a new element to the array. The thing is, when I add an element, the `Picker` choices are not updated. It doesn't work with `DefaultPickerStyle`, but works with `SegmentedPickerStyle`.

The code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView: View {
    @State
    var array : Array<Int> = [Int]()
    @State
    var selection : Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: self.$selection) {
                ForEach(self.array, id : \.self) { i in
                    Text(String(i))
                }
            }
            // uncomment, and picker will refresh upon pushing the button
            //.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            Button(action: {
                self.array.append(self.array.count)
            }){
                Text("Add me: " + String(self.array.count))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleView()
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this? I really need to update the Picker (in its default styling). Xcode Version 11.2.1 (11B500).

Comment: see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660945/swiftui-picker-content-not-refreshed-when-adding-element

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Indeed, I found the workaround there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @e-coms pointed out, there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660945/swiftui-picker-content-not-refreshed-when-adding-element). An acceptable workaround found by [@p-ent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58779351/946635) ([github](https://github.com/peterent/SwiftUIBug)) is to re-assign a unique `.id(...)` for  `Picker` on each button push, to force its update. Adapted to my question:

UPD: even better, thanks @e-coms

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView: View {
    @State
    var array : Array<Int> = [0,1,2]
    @State
    var selection : Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: self.$selection) {
                ForEach(self.array, id : \.self) { i in
                    Text(String(i))
                }
            }
            .id(self.array)

            Button(action: {
                self.array.append(self.array.count)
            }){
                Text("Add me: " + String(self.array.count))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleView()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice .id(). You don't need to add an extra state, just use  `.id(self.array)` which make it nicer.